# Castor XML Mapping:How to map a string child

Tags: java, xml, mapping, castor

Here is the xml:

```
  <infoAdicional>
    <campoAdicional nombre="correo:">edu.ec@hotmail.com</campoAdicional>
  </infoAdicional>
```

And here is my mapping file:

```
<class name="ec.eac.sitac.esigef.InfoAdicional">
    <map-to xml="infoAdicional" />

    <field name="campoAdicional" type="ec.eac.sitac.esigef.CampoAdicional">
        <bind-xml name="campoAdicional" node="element" />
    </field>
</class>

<class name="ec.eac.sitac.esigef.CampoAdicional">
    <map-to xml="campoAdicional" />

    <field name="nombre" type="java.lang.String">
        <bind-xml name="nombre" node="attribute" />
    </field>
</class>
```

When I try to convert the xml to a java object, an error appears. The reason is that I don´t know how to map the email text. This is not an element nor an attribute. How am I supposed to map this string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I treated the field "campoAdicional" class as a String and I just ignored the attribute nombre="correo:".

```
<class name="ec.eac.sitac.esigef.InfoAdicional">
    <map-to xml="infoAdicional" />
    <field name="campoAdicional" type="java.lang.String">
        <bind-xml name="campoAdicional" node="element" />
    </field>
</class>
```